# Tooltip flows under header

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The tooltip for the impact widget on the profile page flows under the header.

[image: screen shot from Web Apps]

(I have checked only on Ask Different and it behaves correctly there.)

[image: screen shot from Ask Different]

Affected browsers:

- Safari (Mac OS)
- Google Chrome (Windows 8.1/ Windows 7)

Comment: This is still happening to me.

Comment: Still happening.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip for the Impact widget is displaying under the bottom of the **people reached** label. So it is not overlap with the header.

It has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Screenshot for reference:

[image: Impact widget]